# Windows Phone Universal RichEditBox Italic Formatting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How to apply Italic formatting for selected text in `RichEditBox` control ?

I try this code but doesn't work.

```
    private void SetItalic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selection = ContentTxt.Document.Selection;
        // doesn't work
        selection.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.On;
        // this also doesn't work
        selection.FormattedText.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.On;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `FontFamily="Segoe UI"` to your RichEditBox XAML definition. The default font set is "Segoe WP" which apparently doesn't support italics.